# True returning a 1

Tags: php

The false works well but when I return true I get a true1 why?

```
$num = 3;

function number($num)
{
    for($i = 2; $i < $num; $i++) {

        if($num % $i == 0) {
            echo("false");

            return false;
        }
    }
    echo("true");

    return true;
}

 echo number($num);
```

Comment: You may want to read [PHP Boolean Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

Comment: As an aside, what is the intention of the function?  As near as I can tell, you're attempting to determine if `$num` is prime.  You can improve code readability by giving functions and variables meaningful names.  So, instead of `number()`, you could name it something like `is_prime()`.

Comment: So, what you actually need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in PHP `TRUE` is the same as 1 in string format.  However, PHP handles the data type differently that is why you need to use the `===` operator to validate the type and the data.

Any comparisons that you make should be using the `===` operator.

One way to see what is actually coming back is to use `var_dump` on the output.

Comment: You want it to display the literal true?  If yes, then you need to do that manually.

Comment: You need to explain answers like that more clearly.  `true` is _not_ the same as 1.  1 is 'truthy', but it is not the _same_ as 1.  See [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/av4-8ki)

Comment: `TRUE` is also not a string. I could call it a constant, if I was forced to give it a name, but in reality it is just part of the PHP language like `array` or `while`. PHP recognizes all these words as language elements.

Answer (score 1):

echoing out true will always give you 1.  Try

```
var_dump($num);
```

That will show you what the type and value of the variable is.  You will see it as true there.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to echo something value it value will be converted to string. So, you trying to echo boolean. Ok, let's read documentation about [Converting to string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting)

> A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". Boolean FALSE is converted to "" (the empty string).

Answer (score 0):

When you `echo number($num);` `true` is being cast as string, which comes out '1'.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you are implicitly converting the boolean `true` into integer, which the value will be `1`.

To compare strictly, you need to use the type and value comparison, which is `===` operator.

Also, `var_dump()` and `print_r()` displays the type of the variable.